# Returning to wrong activity when back pressed from URI launched PDF

Tags: android, android-intent

Im hoping this is simple, but im fairly confused as to what is going on.  I am launching a PDF from an Imagebutton in an android activity using a piece of code I copied from elsewhere in my app.

```
if (v==imagebutton20) {

                File file = new File("/sdcard/documents/20.pdf");
                  if (file.exists()) {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter, R.anim.zoom_exit);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                        }
                  }
            }   //end of   load
```

The pdf loads fine but when i press back the activity that launched the pdf isnt show, instead it returns to the activity before.  I have tried commenting out the

```
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

but the same effect.  What am i missing?  Sorry but i couldnt make sense of the official android guide, must be having a thick day!

---

Even more confused as I have checked the manifest file, the .xml for the activity (Brain) and yet each time i load the pdf using the code above back takes me back to the wrong activity (main) in my app.  I am calling the Brain activity from Main via an imageview, but that works fine.  When i launch the PDF above from Brain the back button takes me to Main and not the launching activity Brain.

I am using the code above elsewhere in 2 other activites in my app and the back key behaves exactly as you want / expect.  Thats why i started checking the mainfest file, but no idea what im missing.

ANY help would be ace please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain why the following worked, but in case anyone else has a similar issue I solved the problem by:

- Creating a new Android activity in eclipse.
- Copying the code from the misbehaving activity.
- Pasting the code in the newly created activity.

Simple and not really sure why it worked, but it did.